# Compile Errors Java: Boolean Array Method

Tags: java, arrays

getting compile errors and just cannot get this code to work the way I need it to, it's beginning to drive me mad! Basically I am trying to get my boolean array in my method to iterate through the array, find out if False is listed more consecutively or if True is and return either true or false. In my program the array i have listed should return false. Any ideas? thanks in advance.

```
public class trueOrfalse
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      boolean[] guess = {false,true,false,false,false,true,true};
      boolean result = longerTF(guess);
   }


   public static boolean longerTF(boolean[] guess)
   {
   int variable = 0;
   for(int x = 0; x < guess.length; x++)
   {
       if(guess[x] > true)
       {
          return true;
       }
       else 
       {
           return false;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: **What** compiler errors?

Comment: You should fix your indentation.

Comment: What is `guess[x] > true` supposed to mean?

Comment: `>` only works with numbers. And you don't seem to know how this algorithm should look like. You definitely need a nested loop or another method for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "corrected" version:

```
public class trueOrfalse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean[] guess = { false, true, false, false, false, true, true };

        boolean result = longerTF(guess);

    }

    public static boolean longerTF(boolean[] guess) {

        int variable = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < guess.length; x++) {
            if (guess[x]) {
                variable++;
            }
        }
        return (variable > (guess.length-variable));
    }
}
```

You forgot one closing braket `}`, a return statement and boolean compare cannot be with `<` or `>`.

Comment: hi thanks for sharing an answer, what I was up to mainly was trying to have my method iterate through the passed down array. Look at the boolean values and identify if false is printed consecutively more in the array or if true is. False is printed consecutively more therefore i would like my method to return false up to main.

Comment: The loop is meaningless in this code as it will exit after the first iteration. And `if (guess[x] == true) {return true;}`, really? Testing a `boolean` against a `boolean` to get a `boolean` in order to return the same `boolean` is more than a little redundant.

Comment: false is listed more consecutively in the array then true

Comment: @LewBloch need to read my post! I just corrected the it to run through the compiler. The code is semantically completely incorrect.

Comment: @LewBloch but you're right ... can't keep an answer like that. Changed the code to make at least a little sense.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison​ operators `>`, etc., are neither legal nor meaningful for `boolean` operands. What did you intend `guess[x] > true` to accomplish?

Since `guess` is a `boolean[]` you are allowed to test

```
if (guess[x])
```

or

```
if (! guess[x])
```

and to

```
return guess[x];
```

EDIT
You want the loop to count consecutive values. This loop does not, but it shows how such a structure works for a simpler problem.

```
public boolean dominant(boolean[] guess) {
  int tCount = 0;
  for (int ix = 0; ix < guess.length; ++ix) {
    if (guess[ix]) {
      ++tCount;
    }
  }
  return tCount >= guess.length / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know where to start

first of all this is wrong

```
if(guess[x] > true)
```

it should be

```
if(guess[x]==true)
```

since an if statement expects a boolean result and you have boolean values in your array this will have the same effect

```
if(guess[x])
```

you also missed a case. when the array is empty you would never run into the for loop, but your method still needs to return a boolean value. you could throw a runtime-exception or a default value like `return false;` at the end of your method

your for-loop does not make sense, since your method will return a result within the first iteration (if the array is not empty). your longerTF method could be also looking like this

```
public static boolean longerTF(boolean[] guess) {
    if(guess.length>0)
        return guess[0];
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The array must not be empty");
}
```

i'd suggest a general book like "programming: Learn the Fundamentals of Computer Programming Languages". you need to understand first the basics of programming before you try to implement anything.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by everyone above. You can't use `>` to compare two booleans.

For your purpose to count the number of consecutive true/false, you need two different counters. You can run a loop and keep incrementing the counter as you encounter repeated item of true/false, if not you can just reset the counter to 1. I have put on a hasty solution below to give you an idea. I haven't tested it well it seems to work. Hope this helps.

```
public class trueOrfalse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean[] guess = { false,true,false,false,false,true,true };
        boolean result = longerTF(guess);
        System.out.println("result: " +result);
    }

    public static boolean longerTF(boolean[] guess) {

        int consecutiveFalseCount = 1;
        int consecutiveTrueCount = 1;

        for (int x = 0; x < guess.length; x++) {
            if (guess[x] == true) {
                if(x!=0 && x<guess.length){
                   if(guess[x-1] == true){
                       consecutiveTrueCount = consecutiveTrueCount + 1;
                   } else {
                       consecutiveTrueCount = 1;
                   }
                }
            } else {
                if(x!=0 && x<guess.length-1){
                       if(guess[x-1] == false){
                           consecutiveFalseCount = consecutiveFalseCount + 1;
                       } else {
                           consecutiveFalseCount = 1;

                       }
                    }
                } 
        }

        System.out.println("Consecutive True count: " +consecutiveTrueCount);
        System.out.println("Consecutive False count: " +consecutiveFalseCount);

        if(consecutiveTrueCount>consecutiveFalseCount){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```